# German word meaning "Converting an audio record to written text"

Tags: single-word-request

What is the German word for "Converting an audio record to written text"?

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please [edit] your question to add some details, in particular what kind of conversion you are talking about (human or automatic) and what is converted (mainly speech or more).?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest single-word translation for that process would be *Verschriftlichung*, the verb *verschriftlichen*, which means the conversion of spoken language to written text. That should include putting live as well as recorded speech into writing, be it manual writing or typing into a machine.

Comment: This solution only seems to capture the "to written text" part, but is not actually restricted to an "audoi record" as its source.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that's what I thought too. The target is given, but not the source...

Comment: I think that the source is a bit too specific for finding a 100% accurate translation.

Answer (score 6):

Another translation is "[transkribieren](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/transkribieren)".

Comment: That's the word I thought of first, too. But I highly doubt that this word fits the question asked. I would recommend that you might have another look at the definition of the word; "transkribieren" means either to transform text into another text format or phonemic convertion of spoken language into text.

Comment: @Locké Yes and no. I also found a definition that defines "transkribieren" as bringing the spoken word to "paper". But, I am not an expert...

Comment: Vielleicht auch protokollieren, aber das ist meist eine verkürzte, zusammenfassende Niederschrift.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible single word translation could be "niederschreiben"

Comment: This can also refer to bringing thoughts to text form, not necessarily audio information.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper correct, but the context would make the meaning clear, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well, the context can also make the meaning clear for something totally generic like "übertragen" or "konvertieren".